# Collapse text - nstextview

Tags: html, nstextview, code-folding

I need to create a simple nstextview for write some html code, I'm not interested (for now) to have color on syntax but I must have the text collapse for some tag.

I try to search around but I don't find any thread, post, article that explain some tips for do it but I don't fin nothing. The only thing that I find is library (ACEView) but I don't I can not install it because I get an error of header not found.

Any tips for collapsing text?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of the time and new versions, but ACEView works just great!

https://github.com/ACENative/ACEViewSwift